# Secure Android Server data upload over http

Tags: android, http, ssl, ssh

I am building an app that creates a http connection between Android and a specific Server. I transfer data using JSON and all is going well, but now I am trying to secure the connection, by which I mean I don't want a third party to view the data being uploaded. The Server doesn't use SSL certificates and so I am currently thinking of how to implement a secure connection. So far I have two ideas:

- Create a self-signed certificate and put it on the server file system. Problem with htis is that the Server owner doesn't want me poking around his system. I'd rather not get into a debate with him about it
- Use Jsch (or other) SSH library to create a secure connection. Problem with thisis, I have never used SSH before.

What do you recommend? Is there another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get them to setup SSL on the server and be done with it. Since the server has to decrypt the data, you need to do *something* on the server, whether that is installing a key and certificate or modifying the web app to decrypt your data. Using SSL is by far the best option. SSH can be tricky, and they might be less likely to allow SSH connections from mobile devices than regular HTTP(S).

Comment: Thanks. SSH does look tricky, but I dont think anything needs to be en/decrypted over SSH since the channel is secure. Also will the self-certified SSL interfere with regular web traffic? Browsers may not recognize it.

Comment: Same goes for SSL. You would still need to generate a key pair for SSH, it doesn't really make it any easier. Setting up local port forwarding to tunnel HTTP over SSH requires an account on the server too. Since you most probably don't have root on the device, you can't forward port 80, so you need to use 8080 or something similar. Buy a couple of beers to the admin, and get him to setup SSL.

Comment: Thanks. But will a self-signed SSL certificate mess up the server's web usability? Broswers may reject the certificate?

Comment: Sure they will. If you need SSL for web users, get a certificate from a browser-supported CA. But if users are now accessing it via HTTP, no  one will use HTTPS URL. Or, to be sure, set up a separate virtual host for your app. Talk to the admin :)